# Set Owner of wpf window by window of other application, is it possible?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I would like to make an application by wpf which could overlay a specific windows application.
It means, when I run my application and specify Notepad as target application. At that time, anytime Notepad application got focus, my application will take over the focus & prevent user handle directly Notepad.

It is quite simple in case of 2 windows in same application ( we can set owner of child window & showdialog)

So, I wonder that if it is possible to get the handle of window of other application to set owner for our application.

Thanks for any comments or discussion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the general sense, yes - it's possible. But you will have to use Platform APIs in order to obtain the handle of Windows that are not in your process.

Here's a list of [Window-related Functions in the Win32 Platform API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468919%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

You may then by able to make your WPF window appear on top of the other window. But just know that depending on your end goal this might not be the best way to achieve your desired results!

Comment: Thank bro, I can get the handle of target window now. My job now is striking to set the position, the owner of my wpf window by that handle to overlap the target window. I'm trying. ^_^. Thanks!

Comment: great, after setting owner with the support of WindowInteropHelper. The overlay form work well to cover target window, even in case of alt-tab. But one more issue is that, user move or resize the target windows. LOL. Is there any recommendation?

Comment: @kidgu bit.ly/16WOzK6 has a solution for positioning and sizing.

Comment: Miky do you know why this works on .NET 4 but not on .NET 3.5?

Comment: Find a good example of sizing to match another window here: bit.ly/16WOzK6